# "Check for Running Processes" is not working in Install4j

Tags: install4j

The objective here is to check if any of the previously installed launchers are still running, and if they are, stop the installation (or update) and display an error message to the user telling them that they need to stop it first.

In install4J doc, it clearly states that:

> Generated installers will detect if any of the previously installed
> launchers are still running and will ask the user to shutdown these
> applications. This happens when the "Install files" action or a "Check
> for running processes" action is executed.

Problem is, "Install files" is already added, but nothing happens whenI try to execute a launcher while others are still running. And so I added the action "Check for running processes" as well, but still nothing happens.

The update goes smoothly until the end with no error message whatsoever even though there's a previously installed launcher still running.

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S: I should also add that I still haven't tested it on Linux. So far, I have only tested it on Windows and it's not working (even when I choose Allow termination or Terminate immediately as close strategy).

**UPDATE**: Reading the logs in .install4j/installation, I found this:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.CheckRunningProcessesAction [ID 24749]: Execute action
       Property message: install4j has detected that  PID Server is currently running.

Please close the following processes, then click Retry to continue, or Cancel to exit.
       Property closeStrategy: Terminate immediately
       Property allowIgnore: false
       Property timeOut: 5000
       Property includeLaunchers: true
       Property additionalExecutables: [pid.exe, C:\pid\bin\pid.exe, C:\pid\bin\pid]
       Property rollbackSupported: true
       Execute action successful after 42 ms
```

But I didn't get any of this in GUI mode. No errors are returned during update.

**UPDATE 2**:Tested with install4j8 --> same problem: there's no popup during installation in GUI mode asking me to close the running process before continuing. Is there a property that I need to set for the popup to appear? in installation.log, I can clearly see that install4j is detecting the running process and asking the user to close them, but in GUI mode nothing appears.

Comment: It works for me on Windows. Is the running launcher a generated launcher? Is the "Check for running process" before the "Install files" action? Is this in GUI mode (installer wizard is shown) or in unattended mode? What version of install4j do you use?

Comment: 1. The running launcher is a .exe file in the bin directory of the project. 
2. Yes, I added the action "Check for running processes" before the "Install files" action.
3. Yes, it's in GUI mode.
4. Version of install4j is 6.1.6.
5. I also tried to add manually the name of the file I would like install4j to check which is in ${installer:sys.installationDir}\bin\fileName.exe, but it's still being ignored.

Comment: If the launcher has not been generated by install4j, you have to add it to the "Additional executables" property of the "Check for running processes" action. Use the file chooser to choose them from the distribution tree. Also, 6.1.6 is very old, please try with the current version.

Comment: What if they are not in the file chooser, is there a way I can add them there? Because when I put just the name of the executable in "Additional executables" which is "opsp.exe", nothing happens. Even when I put the full path to the executable, install4j completely ignores it.

Comment: I added the screens to show you exactly what I'm getting. Even when I put the full path in the field "File", it still gets ignored.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how you add files in the distribution tree. I'll add them all and then I'll let you know how it went.

Comment: I added the file manually and now it's being taken into consideration because install4j asks me whether to overwrite it or not. However, it doesn't seem to care about the value of "close strategy". It doesn't terminate the external launcher when I choose "terminate immediately" and it doesn't ask me to close it when I choose "ask user to manually close".

Comment: For debugging, you could try to use a "Run script" action and print the results of `com.install4j.api.windows.WinProcesses.getRunningProcesses()` to check whether the executable you are looking for is included.

Comment: Weird, the executable is not in the list returned by `getRunningProcessess()`. I don't understand why, and also why in `installation.log` install4j is telling me that he's detecting the running executable? I'm pretty sure I put the right path for the executable as well: `${installer:sys.installationDir}/bin/pid.exe`, and in installation.log, I can see that the path of the executable was correctly resolved.

Comment: No, the message in the log file just shows the configuration of the action, and the property "message" is set to the string that would be shown if the action detected one of the processes. In your case, the executable is indeed not detected. Do you see it in process explorer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)? What executable path does it report for process?

Comment: Yes, I see it in process explorer and its path is exactly the path of the executable I'm trying to make install4j detect. Maybe I need to add a screen for the "check for running processes" action? I'm really out of idea as to why install4j is still unable to detect it, but is detecting other processes.

Comment: If `com.install4j.api.windows.WinProcesses.getRunningProcesses()` does not see this executable, then install4j has no way of detecting it.

Comment: Dumb question but Is there a reason why `getRunningProcesses()` can't detect it though? Maybe something to do with permission? Because process explorer, task manager and tasklist are all detecting it, only install4j is failing to do so.

Comment: Difficult to say without further information. Can you send the executable (in a ZIP archive) to support@ej-technologies.com? Then we could try to see if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I will do that. Thank you.